# How to overlay one texture on another one?

Tags: texturing, transparency

Hi guys I have a problem.

I want to project logo bumped texture on other shadder within the same material.
But in the end my background material (concrete) becomes transparent (cus of alpha chanel of the logo texture?).

My logo texture is a black picture with transparency and bump map is a black background and white logo with some blur.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the *Add shader*.
Use the *Mix Shader* with the alpha channel as a mask.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your current setup, you plug an *Image Texture* into the *Base Color* socket and into the *Alpha* socket of the *Principled BSDF*, but it doesn't allow you to display anything in the alpha zone.

To fix this, you can for example plug your *Image Texture* into a *MixRGB*, plug the *Alpha* output into the factor of the *MixRGB*, and choose the color you want for your concrete in the *Color 1* of the MixRGB*, or plug whatever you want into this socket:

[image]