# adding texture on vertex color by mixrgb makes texture image lighter on white vertex color

Tags: texture-baking, vertex-colors

When editing a vertex color and then adding an image as texture on it with mixrgb it is lightening the texture image. i only changed the vertex color.

When it is on brown the texture image is correct but with white it is lighter. what am i doing wrong.
[image: texture on brown]

[image: texture on white vertex color]

Comment: Adding colors lightens them. In particular, adding anything to white results in white.

Comment: Enabling "Clamp" on Mix Node should fix that ...

Comment: As already mentioned, don't use "Add" change the blend mode to something else like multiply or overlay, scroll down for the examples:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html

Comment: Thanks guys for all the suggestions when Scurest added his node i tried all blend modes. found out that if i use color blend mode the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also adding up the alphas, and using the alpha of both textures as a factor for *Mix RGB Node* in standard *Mix* mode.

[image]

Basically the same as [How to overlay one texture on another one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/199473/60486)