# How do I use image textures to "mask" metallic elements?

Tags: node-editor, image

First time poster here.

I'm using Blender to create 3D renders of products which my company is manufacturing.

With regards to the labels that I am applying to the products, the labels will have layered elements to them, such as a matte label with metallic/glossy elements.

Up until now I have merely duplicated the "label" and hovered it extremely close to the layer under it to give the impression that the multiple labels are seen as one, for example:

Base layer - Scale: 1
Metallic Layer - Scale: 1.00001
Glossy layer - Scale: 1.0002

I know there is a way to create this same effect within one "label" using the node editor, whereby I can plug in an image texture to the metallic/clearcoat to "mask" the label so that the image plugged into those sections will appear as either metallic or glossy, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any assistance would be much appreciated - I've attached a screenshot of the metallic element I'm using but if I could combine all metallic/glossy/matte elements into one that would be a million times better for us.[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello it's hard to understand, do you have an image of the kind of thing you want to achieve and the kind of logo image you have?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/id-like-to-have-portions-of-a-texture-not-glossy https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199473/how-to-overlay-one-texture-on-another-one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208639/how-to-mix-three-different-shaders-on-the-same-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material/